# Interview: Summing numbers in two linked lists

Tags: c++, list, recursion, linked-list

During an interview yesterday, I was asked how I would go about summing the values of two singly linked lists that contained digits. They also said the lists could be unequal lengths.

I asked if the list was stored backwards, as that's how I learned about it at uni, but they said no, it was stored forward.  They also said I couldn't simply reverse the lists, add then, then reverse it to get it forward again because that option required too much processing.  This sort of solution is all I've been able to find online.

I was unable to give an answer, even after they hinted that I should be doing this with a recursive function.

Can anyone help me out with what the solution would have been. This was for a C++ job and I'm hoping that if I ever get called back and I'm able to explain I researched the solution, they might see that as a good sign. Thank you.

For those confused about how the summation is supposed to work, it was presented in this way.

List 1: 1->2->9
List 2: 1->3

So since the numbers are stored forward, I would need to begin by adding the 9 and 3 (end of both lists).  Then take the 1 carry and do 1 + 2 + 1.  Etc.

Comment: Sounds like a C question. Why recursion???

Comment: What exactly were you supposed to calculate? l1[0]+l2[0] -> l3[0], or would it be l1[0]+l1[1]+... -> sum? I don't really get it ;)

Comment: It shows that your interviewer was stupid. Doing it recursively is at least as slow as simply counting the lists length once. Instead of reversing the lists directly, he wants to use the stack as a reverse list. If you want I can write the code, but at this point it should be quite clear.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little confused too. What about summing two linked lists is difficult? Can't you just iterate through them and add up the numbers?

Comment: quite a vague question as there are no details given on what kind of linked list is being used, if it's an std::list, you can use std::accumulate

Comment: @cli_hlt: I'm confised by that too, I even thought the lists would represent numbers in base-10, each item being a digit.

Comment: @xanatos, if you could provide an example, that would be great. I'm confused as to if I would need two stacks.

Comment: @jpalecek Yeah that must be the case. Otherwise the question (and the partial answers to it) makes no sense.

Comment: If your interviewer had a script in mind for how you were to solve it, that script should be built into the question itself.  Otherwise he should have let you solve it however you wanted--let you get it working--and then impose additional constraints to see how you react.  Anyhoo...if you're really interested in the job for some reason, it can't hurt to send follow-up solution(s) that demonstrate good style as well as hard data on metric comparisons of alternative  methods.

Comment: Modified with a second method that uses a scratchpad but traverses only once the lists.

Answer (score 4):

You count the length of both lists. You pad at the beginning the shorter list with a number of  0 digits so that they are equal in length. Now you pad both numbers with an extra 0 (it will be used by the carry of the first digits. So that it's possible that 9 + 1 = 10).
You create a third linked list of length equal to the previous two.

Now you do a class like this:

```
class Digit
{
    public:
    Digit *Next;
    int Dt;
}
```

and a function like this:

```
int Sum(const Digit* left, const Digit* right, Digit* runningTotal)
{
    int carry = 0;

    if (left->Next != NULL)
    {
        carry = Sum(left->Next, right->Next, runningTotal->Next);
    }

    carry += left->Dt + right->Dt;

    runningTotal->Dt = carry % 10;

    carry /= 10;

    return carry;
}
```

- This is "version 0".
- In "version 1" you remove the extra padding for the last carry and you add it only if needed.
- In "version 2" you remove unnecessary "0" digits from the front of the linked lists.
- In "version 3" you create the `runningTotal` linked list directly in Sum. You give to the first level Sum only the "Head" of the Running Total.
- In "version 4" instead of padding the shorter LL, you pass a parameter on the number of digits to skip from the longest LL (this is the most difficult passage).

There is another possibility, much more complex, but that doesn't require to pre-count the length of the lists. It uses two recursive functions:

The first recursive function simply traverses left and right while both are present. If both finishes at the same time then you can simply roll-back as in the previous example.

If one of them finishes before the other, then you use another recursive function like this (the initial value of *extraDigits is 1):

```
void SaveRemainingDigits(const Digit *remaining, int *extraDigits, int **buffer)
{
    int currentDigit = *extraDigits - 1;

    *extraDigits = *extraDigits + 1;

    if (remaining->Next)
    {
        SaveRemainingDigits(remaining->Next, extraDigits, buffer);    
    }
    else
    {
        *buffer = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * extraDigits);
    }

    (*buffer)[currentDigit] = remaining->Dt;
}
```

when this function finally returns, we have a scratchpad from where to extract the digits and the length of the scratchpad

The innermost level of our first recursive function has now to sum its current digit of the shortest linked list with the last digit of the scratchpad and put the current digit of the longest linked list in the scratchpad in place of the digit just used. Now you unroll your recursive function and you use the scratchpad as a circular array. When you finish unrolling, then you add elements to the runningTotal linked list taking them directly from the scratchpad.

As I've said, it's a little complex, but in 1-2 hours I could write it down as a program.

An example (without carry)

```
1 2 3 4
6 5
```

you recurse the first two elements. So you have

```
1-6 (in the first level)
2-5 (in the second level)
```

Now you see that the second list is finished and you use the second function.

```
3 (extraDigit enters as 0, is modified to 1. currentDigit = 0)
4 (extraDigit enters as 1, is modified to 2. currentDigit = 1. 
   malloc of 2 elements,
   buffer[currentDigit] = 4 => buffer[1] = 4)

unroll and we return to the previous row

3 (currentDigit = 0
   buffer[currentDigit] = 3 => buffer[0] = 3)
```

Now we return to the previous function

```
2-5 (in the second level, 
     with a lengthBuffer == 2, 
     we set index = length(buffer) - 1
     currentDigitTotal = 5 + buffer[index] => currentDigitTotal = 5 + 4
     buffer[index] = 2 => buffer[1] = 2;
     index = (index - 1 + lengthBuffer) % lengthBuffer => index = 0

1-6 (in the first level, 
     with a lengthBuffer == 2, 
     index = 0,
     currentDigitTotal = 6 + buffer[index] => currentDigitTotal = 6 + 3
     buffer[index] = 1 => buffer[0] = 1;
     index = (index - 1 + lengthBuffer) % lengthBuffer => index = 1

now we exited the recursive function. 
In an external function we see that we have a buffer. 
We add its elements to the head of the total.

Our Linked list now is 9-9 and our buffer is 1,2 with index 1

for (int i = 0; i < lengthBuffer; i++)
{
    runningTotal.AddHead(buffer(index));
    index = (index - 1 + lengthBuffer) % lengthBuffer
}
```

Comment: What I'd like to know is if this explanation was clear... Is anyone able to comprehend what I've written or is it only gibberish?

Comment: The scratchpad bit was hard to follow, but what recursive description isn't?

Comment: Suppose length of L1 is 1000 and length of L2 is 200, are you going to pad 800 zeroes at the beginning of L2? Don't you think that's quite inefficient?

Comment: @Mag That was "version 0". As I've written then there are many optimizations you can do. What you want is "version 4"... But in the end this is more a theoretical problem than a practical problem.

Answer (score 2):

I will approach this problem in something like this

Let's suppose the 2 lists are : 
1->2->7->6->4->3  and 
5->7->2

The sum is  `1->2->7 + Sum(6->4->3, 5->7->2)`

Now we make a function that take 2 lists of same size and returns their sum

which will be something like

```
list1->val + list2->val + Sum(list1->next, list2->next)
```

with base case `if(list1->next == NULL) return list1->val+list2->val;`

Note :: we can handle the carry in next pass easily or you can handle that in our sum function itself

So after all this our ans will be `1->2->7->11->11->5`
then recursively do %10 and take carry and add it to previous value.

so final ans will be `1->2->8->2->1->5`

Answer (score 0):

I would have created a node like *head or *tail to store the address of the node that I started from, then iterate through the list making sure im not back at my start point. This doesn't require to to have to count the length of each, which sounds inefficient.

As for the recursiveness just do this check at the top of the function and return (node->value + myfunct(node->prev));  It'd be more efficient given you're doing the math once.

Answer (score 0):

The lists "1, 2, 9" and "1, 3" each represent the numbers "129" and "13", in which case the sum is "142".

**Using recursion**

- Compute the length of each list.
- If the lengths differ, pad the shortest with zeroes at the beggining.
- Iterate over the lists recursively, returning: a) the carry number if any, or zero otherwise, and b) the tail of the list.

In pseudocode:

```
def sum_lists_rec(a, b, start_a, start_b, length_a, length_b):
    """Returns a pair of two elements: carry and the tail of the list."""

    if the end of the lists:
        return (0, empty_list)

    result = sum_lists_rec(a+1, b+1, start_a+1, start_b+1, length_a, length_b)

    carry = (a[0] + b[0] + result[0]) / 10
    digit = (a[0] + b[0] + result[0]) % 10

    return (carry, [digit] ++ result[1])

def sum_lists1(a, b):
    length_a = length(a)
    length_b = length(b)

    if length_a < length_b:
        a = [0, 0, ..., (length_b - length_a)] ++ a
    else if length_b < length_a:
        b = [0, 0, ..., (length_a - length_b)] ++ b

    result = sum_lists_rec(a, b, length_a, length_b, 0, 0)

    if result[0] != 0:
        return [result[0]] ++ result[1]
    else:
        return result[1]
```

As an alternative, you can use a stack:

- Compute the length of each list.
- If the lengths differ, pad the shortest with zeroes at the beggining.
- Push each digit of both lists on the stack.
- Pop the stack until is empty, creating the new list.